# string matching in an alpbetically ordered list (the MATLAB way)

Tags: matlab

I have a large alphabetically ordered cell array of strings (~495 thousand), with lots of duplicates (which are next to each other, because it's alphabetical).

For a given look-up string, I need to find all the strings in the list which will match the one I pass in.

I've been using `strcmp(lookUpString,list)` to do this, but this is extremely slow-- I think it's going through each value in the list to compare, because it doesn't know it's alphabetically sorted.

I could write a while loop to iterate through the list to compare each string using `strcmp` until I find the block of strings I want (and then stop), but I was wondering if there was a "matlab" way of doing this (i.e. performing logical comparison operations on a sorted array).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? In mine, when I created a cell array of 400K 100-letter random strings and search for one of them using strcmp it takes 0.024816 seconds. It's a MEX file actually. I'm using 2011A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I was not satisfied with my earlier "Method 3" so I've just re-jigged it a little to get better performance. It now runs almost 10 times faster than a naive `strcmp`.

`strcmp` wins on my machine (2011b on Linux Mint 12). In particular, it works much better than `ismember`. However, you can gain a bit of an extra speed up if you do some manual presorting yourself. Consider the following speed test:

```
NumIter = 100;
N = 495000;
K = N / 20;
List = cell(N, 1);
for i = 1:20
    List(i*K - K + 1:i*K) = cellstr(char(i+96));
end

StrToFind = cell(NumIter, 1);
for j = 1:NumIter
    StrToFind{j} = char(round(rand * 20) + 96);
end

%# METHOD 1 (ismember)
tic
for j = 1:NumIter
    Index1 = ismember(List, StrToFind{j});
    Soln1 = List(Index1);
end
toc

%#METHOD 2 (strcmp)
tic
for j = 1:NumIter
    Index2 = strcmp(StrToFind{j}, List);
    Soln2 = List(Index2);
end
toc

%#METHOD 3 (strmp WITH MANUAL PRE-SORTING)    
tic
for j = 1:NumIter
    CurStrToFind = StrToFind{j};
    K = 100;
    I1 = zeros(K, 2); I1(1, :) = ones(1, 2);
    I2 = zeros(K, 2); I2(end, 1) = 1; I2(end, 2) = N;
    KDiv = floor(N/K);
    for k = 2:K-1
        CurSearchNum = k * KDiv;
        CurListItem = List{CurSearchNum};
        if CurListItem < CurStrToFind; I1(k, 1) = 1; end;
        if CurListItem > CurStrToFind; I2(k, 1) = 1; end;
        I1(k, 2) = CurSearchNum; I2(k, 2) = CurSearchNum;
    end
    a = find(I1(:, 1), 1, 'last');
    b = find(I2(:, 1), 1, 'first');
    ShortList = List(I1(a, 2):I2(b, 2));
    Index3 = strcmp(CurStrToFind, ShortList);
    Soln3 = ShortList(Index3);
end
toc
```

The output is:

```
Elapsed time is 6.411537 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.396239 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.150143 seconds.
```

Comment: +1: other than some minor optimizations I could suggest (conversion to double is unnecessary for comparisons, extract `StrToFind{j}` only once at the top, ...), I'd say this is the best one.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Cheers Rody, I've incorporated your optimizations. I imagine performance could be improved if one were to add some more `if` statements (ie divide `List` up into quarters or even eighths), but I was only willing to go through so much pain :-)

Comment: Looking at the `ismember` documentation, you shouldn't even need a loop.  It will compare every entry in the first list against every entry in the second.

Comment: @BenVoigt The loop is used for the purposes of the speed test so that the tic toc times are reasonably large. You'll notice that I'm actually looping over the whole method, not `List` (ie the loop has nothing to do with `ismember`). Set `NumIter` at the top of my code to 1 and you'll see what I mean :-)

Comment: Wait, you're not looping to `N`.... that means you're only searching for items found early in the set.  Although I guess if it's building an entire match mask, not just returning the first match, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Just so I know we're on the same page, you could remove the loops entirely from my code above without affecting the three methods. The loops are ONLY there for the sake of the speed test. I don't know what you mean by "searching for items found early in the set"? For `ismember` (ie Method 1), the whole list is searched and an index of all matches is returned. For Method 3, I use conditional `if` statements to work out which portion of `List` the sought after strings lie in and then search only that portion of `List`.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I'm looking at the `j` index, which is a small integer, and thinking you're searching for all copies of element `j` in the set.  But you're pulling that from a different randomly generated list.  I'm too tired to think, obviously.

Comment: @BenVoigt No worries. I can see how it would be confusing if you missed the code that builds the randomly generated list :-)

Answer (score 1):

[ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) is your friend. Instead of linear search, [it does binary search.](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9NIE1N/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-9NIE1N)

Comment: `ismember` appears to run much more slowly than `strcmp` for the speed test I set up. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try binary-search.

It is almost 13(!) times faster:

```
Elapsed time is 7.828260 seconds.    % ismember
Elapsed time is 0.775260 seconds.    % strcmp
Elapsed time is 0.113533 seconds.    % strmp WITH MANUAL PRE-SORTING
Elapsed time is 0.008243 seconds.    % binsearch
```

This is the bin-search code i'm using:

```
function ind = binSearch(key, cellstr)
    % BINSEARCH  that find index i such that cellstr(i)<= key <= cellstr(i+1)
    %
    % * Synopsis: ind = binSearch(key, cellstr)
    % * Input   : key = what to search for
    %           : cellstr = sorted cell-array of string (others might work, check strlexcmp())
    % * Output  : ind = index in x cellstr such that cellstr(i)<= key <= cellstr(i+1)
    % * Depends : strlexcmp() from Peter John Acklam’s string-utilities, 
    %             at: http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/software/util/strutil/
    %
    % Transcoded from a Java version at: http://googleresearch.blogspot.it/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html
    % ankostis, Aug 2013

    low = 1;
    high = numel(cellstr);

    while (low <= high)
        ind = fix((low + high) / 2);
        val = cellstr{ind};

        d = strlexcmp(val, key);
        if (d < 0)
            low = ind + 1;
        elseif (d > 0)
            high = ind - 1;
        else
            return;     %% Key found.
        end
    end
    ind = -(low);       %% Not found!
end
```

where you can get `strlexcmp()` from Peter John Acklam’s string-utilities, at:
http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/matlab/software/util/strutil/

And finally this is the testing script i used:

```
%#METHOD 4 (WITH BIN-SEARCH)    
tic
for j = 1:NumIter
    Index1 = binsearch(StrToFind{j}, List);
    Soln4 = List(Index1);
end
```

Note that results might be different with lengthier strings.